# Which Collection would do this?

Tags: java, collections

I am reading following data -

```
Year, No, Name, 
2009, 1, ABC
2009, 2, PQR
2009, 3, XYZ
2010, 1, BCD
2010, 2, DEF
2010, 3, JKL
2011, 1, FGH
2011, 2, IJK
2011, 3, LMN
```

Its a sample, there are thousands of these type. 
I need to display the unique `Year` value in JList and for the selected `Year`, I have to give a CheckBox, which if selected, would display the `Name` sorted on `No`, otherwise sorted on `Name`.

Comment: Don't you want to create a class e.g. `Baby` that has three fields (`Year`, `No`, and `Name`) and put instances of it in e.g. an ArrayList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need looks like a `Map`, key will be the `Year`, and value will be a list of `No` and `Number` (you need to create your own class).

Then you need to create two `Comparator`, one is based on `Name`, the other is `No`. So when checkbox is checked, you use `Name`-based comparator to sort the list, when unchecked, use `No`-based comparator to sort the list.

Comment: @wyz- Yes using 2 Comparators, I can get the necessary output.. Thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Set<YourStruct>>
```

with year as a key? YourStruct - bean, holding year, no and name.  You can use Collections.sort() for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need the years sorted too, so as top-level use **TreeMap** with year as key, the value will be your class wrapping two **TreeSets** - on for No, one for Name - they will be sorted just by adding values to it, plus they do not allow duplicates.

Or do not create the wrapping class and use two TreeMaps - this is not a big difference.

Comment: No I don't need YEARS to be sorted. The distinct list of Years is already populated in the JList. So based on this JList value ie Year, I need to retrieve the Names in another JList. Now the order of retrieving Names should be based on either Names or No. The default option is No, as you can see from the above sample

Comment: I see, did not read that carefully - so you can use any HashMap at top level (or HashTable if you need synchronized access) and use TreeMap for the case when you need Name sorted by No (he key).